# How to: asp.net Handler?

Tags: asp.net, mapping, handlers

i'm starting to develop my first asp.net web application.
I've read a lot about the Handlers, but really i can't understand how to map the handler in the web.config.

I've tryed to add this code into "system.web" tag

```
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="MyHandler.new" type="MyHandler, MyHandlerAssembly" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

But when i start the application i get an error about integrated pipeline.

Someone can explain how to correctly map the handlers??

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx You can find one more section like system.webServer (for IIS 7.0+).

Comment: Ok, i've solved my problem. I'had to add "<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />" in the web.config, but now i still can't reach the handler with "window.location.href = "MyHandler.new";
Dont' know why, i get error 404